# Review audits load more slowly than other review items, making them obviously audits

Tags: bug, review-audits

Over the last several days, whenever the system decides it's time to quiz me the retrieval of the audit question/posts takes between 3 to 10 seconds to load - **making them rather easy to spot and somewhat defeating the point.**  This happens across all of the review queues.

Is anyone else experiencing this and/or is it already been looked into?  I only tend to frequent SO, I don't know if it's an issue accross the rest of the Stack Exchange network.

Couldn't find any other mention of it and in the interest of fairness I'd rather be kept on my toes...

Comment: I have lag on /review, low quality, and close votes sometimes without audits.

Comment: @JanDvorak no this is a different issue - the review queues are fine, I'm talking specifically about the audit questions.

Comment: @Emissary so does the linked question

Comment: i don't understand how this is a duplicate of the marked question, it refers to a different issue that is apparently fixed, while the issue described here is ongoing. i see this issue all the time, it makes review audits obvious. voting to reopen.

Comment: Let us reopen this!

Comment: Yes, I experienced this too... "ups, taking too long, here comes an audit"

Comment: One year after, this is still an issue.

Comment: Needs more upvotes.

Comment: Definitely still an issue.

Comment: The point is it makes countering robo-reviewing ineffective, on the contrary it's encouraging robo-viewing