# Review tests - delay when loading review suggests it is a test

Tags: bug, review-queues

I would like to bring to your attention that review audits, where you get the message:

> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention...

They are taking **longer to load**, thus reviewer can easily tell that he is being tested and only then be careful about his/her actions.

This lag/delay is easily noticeable - for me it lasts 1-2 seconds.

I suggest the review audits mechanism is improved, so that such scenarios are harder to guess.

Comment: He he. I've noticed this as well. Can be up to 30 seconds or so ...

Comment: How can we provide evidence of timings? I just get "loading ..." or similar as far as I can remember.

Comment: I cannot provide any reliable evidence. But it should be easy to create a manual test case, assign few testers to click-through review queue and I believe the result will be obvious (noticeable delay/lag before test).

Comment: Or if you want - you can create automated tests - calling REST api and do average response times from it. :)

Comment: Hmm. The duplicate ([Review audits load more slowly than other review items, making them obviously audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255703)) doesn't have an answer ...