# Suggested Edits "Pay attention" test is slow to show up and guessable

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits, performance

When you review Suggested Edits (and maybe other review categories), the time the server needs to send back the next edit for review is fast. However, when the algorithm decides to test the user with a spam/vandalism like challenge, the server takes several seconds to bring back the page.

I did an experience over the last weeks by blindly selecting Reject > Spam as the answer when the page takes time to load. It was a 100% pass test and no true negatives.

Shouldn't we get cached prepared test questions ready to be served so that it's transparent from the user experience?

My point is different from the possible duplicate pointed out below in the sense that - in constrast with other cases mentioned like you click on the link, you guess, etc. - I feel that that this lag is not countering the "robo-viewing" part these tests are designed for.

Comment: Well, you actually _paid attention_. So what? The audits are meant to filter out those people who don't do so.

Comment: I amended the comment: that lag is making combat against robo-viewing inefficient IMHO

Comment: Yes, this was mentioned here as well http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255703/review-audits-load-more-slowly-than-other-review-items-making-them-obviously-au